# Append values to array items

Tags: c#, arrays

Can anyone please provide me a more efficient way to do the following:

```
int[] result = { 0, 0 };
foreach(var group in operatorsGroups)
{
    int[] added = { 0, 0 };
    added = somefunction(group);
    result[0] += added[0];
    result[1] += added[1];
}
return result;
```

Something like the following:

```
int[] result = { 0, 0 };
foreach(var group in operatorsGroups)
{       
    result += somefunction(group);       
}
return result;
```

Comment: more effiecient regading what? Lines of code? Speed? Memory? Beautyness? Anyway: best way is to write a unit-test, then refactor and see if it still works.

Comment: and what does this code do?

Comment: If you mean faster, then adding on two discrete variables and building the result array at the end is probably faster.

Comment: At least you can drop the initial value from `added` even though the compiler might optimize it away also. But not necessarily. No reason to assign a value to just replace it with another on the next line.

Comment: if you want to perform something on **every** item, you have to do so on **every** item. I can´t see any way around that. What problem do you have with the code above? Seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: If you want to reduce lines of code... Consider using LINQ.

Comment: @Sisir any example please?

Comment: One advice I can share with you is that "If it is not broken, don't fix it". Premature optimization is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing lines of code using LINQ:

```
List<int> items = activeList.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);
items.Add(itemToAdd);

// If you want to see it as an actual array you can still use ToArray
int[] itemsAsArray = items.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing some heavier work on each iteration then you can use multi threaded or async await concept.

```
    int[] result = { 0, 0 };   
     Parallel.ForEach(operatorsGroups, group =>
        {
            int[] added = { 0, 0 };
            added = somefunction(group);
            result[0] += added[0];
            result[1] += added[1];
        });
   return result;
```